# Yii2 How to Use Html::tag or Html::beginTag

Tags: html, yii2, carousel

i want to echo like this

```
<li>
    <img src="img/h4-slide.png" alt="Slide">
        <div class="caption-group">
            <h2 class="caption title">some_title
                        </h2>
                        <h4 class="caption subtitle">Dual SIM</h4>
                        <a class="caption button-radius" href="some_route"><span class="icon"></span>check</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

here my code for render image carousel :

```
$slides = [];
foreach (Slide::find()->orderBy('sortOrder')->all() as $slide) {
    /** @var $slide common\models\Slide */
    $slides[] = [
        'content' => Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/uploads/slide/' . $slide->id . '.jpg'),
        'caption' => Html::tag('content-group', $slide->title)."<br>".$slide->body,
    ];

}
```

And my carousel :

```
<div class="slider-area">
  <div class="block-slider block-slider4">
<?= Carousel::widget([
    'id' => 'bxlider-home',
    'items' => $slides,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'slide',
        'data-interval' => 3000,
    ],
    'controls' => [
        '<span class="bx-next fa fa-angle-left"></span>',
        '<span class="bx-prev fa fa-angle-right"></span>',
    ],
]) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to Slide->title, slide->body, and some links can be in class caption-group ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create new partial file.

1. Create a new file called `_slider.php`
2. Call `$this->render('_slider')` inside configuration of the slider. Please check below code.

   ```
   $slides = [];
   foreach (Slide::find()->orderBy('sortOrder')->all() as $slide) {
   /** @var $slide common\models\Slide */
   $slides[] = [
   'content' => $this->render("_slider"),
   'caption' => Html::tag('content-group', $slide->title)."<br>".$slide->body,
   ];
   ```

}

You can write `html` inside `_slider.php` easily now. Don't need to use `Html::beginTag()` etc.

Comment: I just want to anchor title and body with tag html, I think the image was appropriate
thank you for your answer, I will try as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Generating Tags

The code generating a tag looks like the following:

```
<?= Html::tag('p', Html::encode($user->name), ['class' => 'username']) ?>
<p class="username">samdark</p>


$options = ['class' => ['btn', 'btn-default']];

echo Html::tag('div', 'Save', $options);
// renders '<div class="btn btn-default">Save</div>'
```

Hyperlinks:

```
<?= Html::a('Profile', ['user/view', 'id' => $id], ['class' => 'profile-link']) ?>
```

Images:

```
<?= Html::img('@web/images/logo.png', ['alt' => 'My logo']) ?>

generates

<img src="http://example.com/images/logo.png" alt="My logo" />
```

Lists:

```
<?= Html::ul($posts, ['item' => function($item, $index) {
    return Html::tag(
        'li',
        $this->render('post', ['item' => $item]),
        ['class' => 'post']
    );
}]) ?>
```

Even more?
[visit](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html)